# CakePHP website not shows changes, unless clear the history

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

I have my website in cakephp and whenever i do some development or update my website javascript and css files. The changes will not show on my users end, unless they clear the history of browser. Is there anyway, so that changes will show automatically. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simplest way is :**

> -> Add "version" in included css and js file path and update while modify

*Example :*

GOTO PATH : `project/src/Template/Layout`

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css('toastr.min.css?ver=1.0'); ?>
```

Comment: You mean on very edit increment the version value? i mean if now it's ver=1.0 on next change make it ver=2.0 or just keep it constant?

Answer (score 3):

CakePHP supports asset timestamping out of the box, see the `Asset.timestamp` configuration option, and the `timestamp` option in the CakePHP 3.6+ URL helper.

With timestamping enabled, the timestamp of the last modification will be added to the asset URL, thus busting the cache.

See also

- **[Cookbook 3.x > Configuration](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#general-configuration)**
- **[Cookbook 3.x > Views > Helpers > Url > Generating URLs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html#generating-urls)**
- **[Cookbook 2.x > Development > Configuration > CakePHP Core Configuration](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#cakephp-core-configuration)**